# Determining which of two layout constraints with different priorities is determining the value of the dimension/anchor they affect

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, nslayoutconstraint

Say I have two NSLayoutConstraints with different priorities that would both affect the height of some view (**middleView**).

Below, middleView is pinned to the bottom of topView and its height is 500, unless the top of bottomView would force it to be smaller.

```
// topView and bottomView have well-defined constraints, and middleView has well defined x-axis/width constraints not shown here
middleView.topAnchor.constraint(isEqual: topView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

let heightConstraint = middleView.heightAnchor.constraint(isEqualToConstant: 500)
heightConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriority.high
heightConstraint.isActive = true

let bottomConstraint = middView.bottomAnchor.constraint(isLessThanOrEqualTo: bottomView.topAnchor, constant: someMargin)
bottomConstraint.isActive = true // priority is .required by default
```

Besides just checking if the height of my view is 500, is there some other way to determine which of these two constraints is "in effect"?  Say bottomView is in such a position that if forces middleView's height to be less than 500, does heightConstraint have some property to determine that it has been bypassed by a constraint with a greater priority than its own?

I would like to use heightConstraint as some sort of 'switch' that triggers something when it is satisfied.

Comment: If they can be simultaneously satisfied, then all of them will be in effect. If they are conflicting, the one with higer priority will take precedence.

Comment: No, there is no property of the constraint that tells you whether it was applied by the autolayout process.

Comment: @mag_zbc - so I'm wondering about the case where the one with the lower priority is not satisfied.  That's what I'm trying to pick up/observe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't be answered because *both* may have some effect. Even when a non-rquired constraint cannot be satisfied, it can influence layout. From the [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH9-SW1):

> Even if an optional constraint cannot be satisfied, it can still influence the layout. If there is any ambiguity in the layout after skipping the constraint, the system selects the solution that comes closest to the constraint. In this way, unsatisfied optional constraints act as a force pulling views towards them.

Auto layout uses a constraint solver to calculate its values. (I believe it's still using [Cassowary](https://cassowary.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/theory.html), or something close to it.) Constraint solvers are basically linear algebra engines. You put a bunch of linear equations into a matrix and you try to solve it for some vector that makes everything "best." One trade-off of that approach is that everything is solved together, and it's not always obvious *why* a particular value was chosen. It's what it is because it's part of the total solution. (In this way, CSP systems are very similar to machine learning systems. They give answers that are "correct," but they don't always provide a step-by-step of their reasoning they way branching-if logic can. It's why they can be so challenging to debug.)

To your question, I would base your logic off the thing you actually care about. "A constraint fired" is never the actual thing you cared about (especially since constraints don't "fire"). You generally care about something in the result (such as the final hight), so you should check that.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thanks for the detailed response!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's not possible.  The alternative would be to compare the dimension/anchor constant in question to the possible values.